# Редирект с определенных страниц и записей WordPess для не залогиненых пользователей

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Есть сайт на WordPress. Стоит задача сделать редирект для не вошедших в систему пользователей на страницу с url `/online-obuchenie/start/` с страницы с `id 5567` и всех её дочерних страниц. А также со всех записей относящихся к категории c url `onlayn-shkola` (или по ее id `204`). Пыталась вот так, но не получается дописать:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page('5567') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( '/online-obuchenie/start/', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: is_category(204) && in_category(204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;

    if ( is_page( 5567 ) || in_category( 204 ) || ( $post && 5567 === $post->post_parent ) ) {
        wp_redirect( '/online-obuchenie/start/', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не компилируемый код) Убери лишнюю строку.

Comment: Теперь плюсую )